# PhoneGap 1.2 fires target of <a href> twice in IOS 5

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova

I'm upgrading my existing PhoneGap application to IOS 5. This also involves upgrading PhoneGap from 0.9.4 to 1.2

Now, a fundemental issue I encounter is that links are followed twice when you tap them. This is my setup:

I dynamically create an anchor element after the OnDeviceReady() event.

```
$('<a></a>').attr('href', 'javascript: log(\'tap!\');').appendTo(...);
```

Now when I tap this link once quickly, this is logged to the console:

> 12:11:34.233: 'tap!'
>  12:11:34.584: 'tap!'

Notice the 200+ ms delay.

When I tap it slowly (keep my finger on the screen longer) this is the result

> 12:11:34.233: 'tap!'
>  12:11:34.234: 'tap!'

This behavior only occurs on an iPhone or the iPhone Simulator. Does anyone else has a similar experience and maybe a solution/workaround?

Comment: Any chance you are using jQuery Mobile as well?  I had an issue previously when dealing with `vclick`. And on a side note, PhoneGap 1.3 was released yesterday http://phonegap.com/2011/12/19/phonegap-1-3-released/

Comment: nope i'm not using jquery mobile, but I'm guessing they share a similar cause.

Thanks for the upgrade notice!

Answer (score 0):

$('').attr('href', 'javascript: log(\'tap!\'); return false;').appendTo(...);

you are probably binding the event to your link twice

you can also look into:
http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/